# Can Workbench 3.1 have access to CDTV CD Rom

Tags: cd-rom, amiga-kickstart, amiga-cdtv, amiga-workbench-3.1

Is it possible to load CDTV.DEVICE and CDFileSystem extracted from CDTV extended rom on Workbench Startup, or manipulate amiCD drivers to load CDTV.DEVICE instead?

My setup is CDTV, KS3.1, TF536 50mhz, MMU, 64MB RAM, SD2IDE, ClassicWB ADVSP. This all works okay and stable with disabled extended rom, but I would love to have native/emulated access to built in CDROM.

When I set CD0 device to cdtv.device and set bufmemtype between 2 and 5 after enqbling extended rom I had the error, not sure what is it referring to, bit I guess this is to do with CD ROM DMA?

Settings:
[image: CD options]

Error when extended rom is enabled
[image: error]

Comment: I tried to start a 3.1 (A600) + extended CDTV rom from WinUAE and it just reboots and reboots... I could boot from a floppy in 1.3 and have access to CD0: though

Comment: is your question about: can I access the CDTV cd-rom without the extended rom?

Comment: CDTV uses extended rom, and this is where CDROM driver sits. Since I switched KS to 3.1 it doesn't pull driver anymore from rom, but once booted to WB3.1 can you just map it and use it?

Comment: from this page http://www.gregdonner.org/workbench/wb_cdtv.html Amiga of Minnesota Interest Groups Alliance (A.M.I.G.A.) has obtained non-exclusive licensing to provide the hardware to upgrade the CDTV to OS 3.1. This involves changing two PROMs in the CDTV, and installing the 3.1 OS ROM at the same time. The machine will then boot to 3.1 from floppy with the CD drive active. It can also boot to 3.1 from the CD drive, but will reboot when the "eject" button is pressed.

Comment: I think you could extract cdtv.device from extended rom (using romsplit) then use it as a device driver for your CD-ROM

Comment: Would you be open to elaborate on this a bit, please? This is very interesting topic for me and I would like to understand it grounds up

Comment: I will try to make that work on a CDTV emulated config. It should work. But as always with device stuff a lot of tweaking is necessary.

Comment: Where do I start to learn? Amiga hardware reference book?

Comment: 8000000B is a coprocessor error... looks completely bogus.

Comment: related/ery similar:http://eab.abime.net/showthread.php?t=104410. Seems that you need to set buffer type to 3 or 4, not 2.

Comment: We just started this topic to get it done, community will benefit a lot from this functionality paired with TF cards. They fit inside the case thanks to great relocator by another exxos member go0se.

Comment: I saw that. You should [edit] your post to show the mountlist you're using for CD0